# Writing to files and I/O

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to write a program that gets a users input that is then written to an output file called `userStrings.txt`. I'm also trying to stop the processing once the user inputs 'done', but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Murray_A04Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    // Name of the file
        String fileName = "userStrings.txt";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            // FileReader reading the text files in the default encoding.
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("userStrings.txt");

            // Wrapping FileReader in BufferedReader.
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

                bufferedWriter.write("A string");
                bufferedWriter.write("Another string");
                bufferedWriter.write("Yet more text...");
                System.out.println("Enter something, DONE to quit: ");
                String input = scan.nextLine();

            // Closing file
                bufferedWriter.close();
        }

        catch (IOException ex){
            System.out.println("Error writing to file " + "userStrings.txt" + "");
        }


    } // End of method header
} // End of class header
```

In order to write to a file, do I still use `System.out.println`? and is the `bufferedWriter.write` even necessary? I'm just trying to understand the I/O and writing to files better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In order to write to a file, do I still use System.out.println?

No.  That writes to standard output, not to your file.

If you are using `println`  then you need to wrap your `BufferedWriter` with a `PrintWriter`.  (Look at the javadocs for the `System` class where the `out` field is documented.)

> and is the bufferedWriter.write even necessary?

If you are going to write directly to the `BufferedWriter` then yes, it is necessary, though you probably need to an appropriate "end of line" sequence.  And that's where it gets a bit messy because different platforms have different native "end of line" sequences.  (If you use `PrintWriter`, the `println` method picks the right one to use for the execution platform.)

> I'm also trying to stop the processing once the user inputs 'done', but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Hint: read about the `Scanner` class and `System.in`.

Answer (score 0):

Right under you take input from the console, run a `while` loop to test that `input` is not equal to `"done"`. Inside the `while` loop, add `input` to your file and get the next line of input.

```
while(!input.toLowerCase().Equals("done"))
{
    bufferedWriter.write(input);
    input = scan.nextLine();
}
```